# Extra carriage return added while generating txt file from bean objects in java using open CSV Writer

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am facing an issue while transforming a bean object into csv/txt formatted file. I have explicitly stated the new line character as '\r\n' in my code which will be overriden by open csv writer's line end character.

Everything is working fine on my local `tomcat` server which is running on Windows i.e. I am getting the CR and LF after each record.But If I try to produce the csv/txt  file on a Linux base machine, what I get is that one record is separated by `CRCRLF` i.e. an extra CR is added from no where after  record.I just want CRLF. The code and configurations are same on my local and remote machine.The only difference is the underlying OS.There is no problem with the data of that row.

I have attached the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puEes.png) for the wrong output file (although this is not the exact but out of approx 450 lines, the 112th line has the problem). I initially had doubt that the specific row which has the problem have a carriage return character with the last Zero (0) but deeply checked the code and found that there is no issue with the data as the Zero (0) is a fixed value and not picked from any database. This fix value is begin read from a JAVA Constant file and is same for each and every row. If there was a problem, then it would have been with every row.

Any Ideas as to why this is happening? I am using `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter#writeAll(List allLines) API`. Default line End character for this writer is `"\n"` (i.e LF), and as mentioned above  I have overridden this by `"\r\n"(i.e. CRLF)` in my code. Is it picking some system default settings for new line markers which are different for windows and linux.If so then why is it doing this when I have explicitly stated the recordTerminator for every type of envirnoment. And if that is the case then how can I fix this. Please I really appreciate any help on this.Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that you are writing values that contain CR already.

If nothing is working for you try using [uniVocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers)' to parse/write as it normalizes line endings and trims white spaces automatically when reading and writing. It also way faster than OpenCSV.

Here's a simple example of how to use it:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); // you'll find many options here, check the tutorial.
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new File("/path/to/your.csv"));
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As mentioned in my previous comment, the values are okay. Myself had the same doubt but as already mentioned, if the values contained extra CR then it would have been with every line but not with only one line since I am using the same ZERO for all the rows.

Comment: Dear Jeronimo Backes, Can you please let me know why an extra CR is appended with a single row only (in the linux environment). We cannot user parser because the file which we are generating is not being read by our system but this file will be read by some external system which is not in control with us. Do you have any suggestion to handle such scenario ?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you need. Can you please provide an example that demonstrates the behavior that is problematic for you, and what the expected output should be? I'll gladly help you out.

Comment: If you can check the screenshot attached in my above comments, 5th row has an extra CR as the line end instead of CRLF . My expectation is that 5th line should not contain an extra CR as the line end character and it should be same as other lines. This extra CR is coming only in linux environment.

Comment: A screenshot doesn't help at all. Can you edit or create a new question listing the relevant java code you are using to generate this output, and a sample of the input data you are sending to the library for writing so I can try to run the code, reproduce the unexpected behavior and see what is going on?